# Windows Camera app stops recording after set time

Tags: windows, video, camera

I have a webcam and am recording with the Windows camera app over night to an external harddrive. It needs to remain on for at least 10 hours at a time. However after 3 hours I am met with the message "Start a new video. This video was getting too large to save as a single file, so we stopped recording and saved the video. Start a new video to continue recording". The issue is not with HDD space as I have plenty. Is there a way I can disable this with the app? If not, is there other software I can use to record longer videos?

Comment: Which webcam and applications are you using?

Comment: @harrymc The name of the app is Windows Camera